# Why my optional captured group in my regex does not work?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Here is a text example that I will usually get:

> CERTIFICATION/repos_1/test_examples_1_01_C.py::test_case[6]
>
> CERTIFICATION/repos_1/test_examples_2_01_C.py::test_case[7]
>
> INTEGRATION/test_example_scan_1.py::test_case
>
> INTEGRATION/test_example_scan_2.py::test_case

Here is the regex I'm using to capture 3 different groups:

`^.*\/(.*)\.py.*:{2}(.*(\[.*\])?)`

**If we take an example with the first line of my examples I should get:**

test_examples_1_BV_01_C - test_case[6] - [6]

**And for the last line:**

test_example_scan_2 - test_case -  None

But if you try this regex you will find out that the first example does not work. I can't get
the [6]. If you remove the "?" you will have no match with line that does not have "[.*]" at the end

So, how can I get all those information ? And what do I do wrong ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^.*\/(.*)\.py.*::(.*?(\[.*?\])?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMHQkn/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.py` - `.py` substring
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `::` - a `::` string
- `(.*?(\[.*?\])?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then an optional Group 3 matching `[`, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and a `]`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's perfect and I perfectly understood what I missed. The only things I changed is here (\[.*?\]). I removed the "?" as it should not be optional

Comment: @CyDevos `.*?` does not mean optional, it means *any zero or more chars *but as few as possible*. If you use `.*` it will match *as many as possible*.

Comment: Oh ok ! "*but as few as possible" That's really interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the help of negated character class you can get all matches and make this regex lot more **efficient**:

```sh
^.*/([^.]+)\.py::([^[]+(\[[^]]*]|))$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wGJDu/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it and it worked. I choose to put this other answer as accepted as it was closer to what I did. Still your answer is really good